# Add color in prawn-graph default theme/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I use [prawn-graph](https://github.com/HHRy/prawn-graph). If the graphs are greater than 5 I get an error:

> /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/prawn-2.2.2/lib/prawn/graphics/colo‌​r.rb:149:in
>   set_color_space': unknown color space: '' (ArgumentError)

Example:

```
require "prawn"
require 'prawn-graph'

series = []
series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([1,7,13,19,25,31],  title: "Bar 1", type: :bar)
series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([2,8,14,20,26,32],  title: "Bar 2", type: :bar)
series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([3,9,15,21,27,33],  title: "Bar 3", type: :bar)
series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([4,10,16,22,28,34],  title: "Bar 4", type: :bar)
series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([5,11,17,23,29,35],  title: "Bar 5", type: :bar)
series << Prawn::Graph::Series.new([6,12,18,24,30,36],  title: "Bar 6", type: :bar)

xaxis_labels = ['0900', '1000', '1100', '1200', '1300', '1400', '1500', '1600', '1700', '1800', '1900', '2000', '2100']

Prawn::Document.generate('tmp/test.pdf') do
    graph series, width: 500, height: 200, title: "A Title for the chart", at: [10,700], xaxis_labels: xaxis_labels
end
```

How add colors in default theme?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change prawn-graph default theme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632792/how-to-change-prawn-graph-default-theme)

Comment: I was recommended "please create a different question for this problem and provide some code".